# Use php in window.location.href

Tags: php, javascript, window.location

This is my js code:

```
function check() {
    var delvar = "<? $_POST["del"]; ?>";
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the article?")
    if (answer) {
        window.location = "adm-site.php?del=" + delvar + "&delete=true";
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that the `delvar` does not work. so the url is just `?del=&delete=true` , instead of e.g. `?del=testarticle&delete=true`

**EDIT:** My `$_POST["del"]` is a select tag with all the articles in it, so you will choose which to delete
The HTML code:

```
<select name="del">
    <option value="none" SELECTED></option>
    all articles echo'ed here by php
</select>
```

Comment: What about `echo`ing the variable content? Sample: `<?=$_POST["del"]?>`

Comment: didnt work with either `echo $_POST["del"]` or `echo $del`

Comment: Ok, so you mean there is a form which contains `select` element and you want to bring that value here in this function? SHow your HTML code.

Comment: Seems like it doesnt even want to insert the ?del=&delete=true in the url no more...

Comment: I think OP wants to insert the value of `select` tag in the redirect URL, so that there he can access it in $_GET array. So, PHP is not gonna work here, because Form is at client-side, user selects/changes the value, and then OP wants this value to embed in `window.location`, which is in JS (still client side). PHP have no authority here.

Comment: You might want to consider using a POST to submit the deletion request instead of a GET request.  See http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx

Comment: @finst33 Can you really see `<? $_POST["del"]; ?>` i.e. PHP code in the JavaScript Code user is getting? Is this all JS code is inline in a .php file? In that case, if you are seeing `$_POST...` there must be a serious problem. In normal cases, User SHOULD see `var delvar = "";`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want this scenario:

- User gets a page with a form containing the select tag having all the articles as values/options.
- User selects an article, which he/she wants to delete.
- User clicks a button.
- Then you want to redirect user to URL `adm-site.php?del=02&delete=true`.

So, in this case, only JavaScript is getting the value of selected article value and embedding it in the redirect URL. So, PHP can do nothing here. All the action is happening client-side.

Try this HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function check(){
        var delvar=document.form1.del.options[document.form1.del.selectedIndex].value;
        //alert(delvar); //debug
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the article?")
        if (answer) {
            //alert("adm-site.php?del=" + delvar + "&delete=true");
            window.location = "adm-site.php?del=" + delvar + "&delete=true";
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
    <select name="del">
        <option value="none" SELECTED>None</option>
        <option value="01">Article 01</option>
        <option value="02">Article 02</option>
        <option value="03">Article 03</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" value="Delete This Article" onclick="check();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[LIVE Demo at JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xDX8U/1/) (Alerting the Redirecting URL)

Things I have edited/changed:

- Added a name to `form` tag.
- Changed the way var `delvar` is assigned the value of currently selected article.

Else all is same code as yours.

As mentioned by [Pheonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212218/phoenix), A bit secure code, doing the same thing as the above one, but by using $_POST. You need to use `$_POST`  array instead of `$_GET` in your `adm-site.php`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function check(){
        var delvar = document.form1.del.options[document.form1.del.selectedIndex].value;
        var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Article " + delvar + " ?");
        if (agree)
            return true ;
        else
            return false ;
    } //function check() ENDS
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="adm-site.php" method="POST">
    <select name="del">
        <option value="none" SELECTED>None</option>
        <option value="01">Article 01</option>
        <option value="02">Article 02</option>
        <option value="03">Article 03</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete this Article" onClick="return check();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo at JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2urMx/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var delvar = '<?php echo $_POST["del"]; ?>';
```

note the `<?php` instead of the discouraged shortcode too.

Comment: Where does the official PHP documentation say that the short_open_tag directive is deprecated?

Comment: changed wording to reflect your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML contains `"` so you need to surround the PHP with single apostrophes. And if you're using the short tag, use it right. So in the end, it should look like this:

```
var delvar = '<?= $_POST["del"]; ?>';
```

Comment: I love it when the cowards vote you down and don't even explain themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to think about it: make a link to the page you want to be sent to, and then give it an `onclick` like this:

```
<a href="/adm-site.php?del=<?php echo $_POST['del']; ?>&delete=true" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Deletion?')" >Delete</a>
```

This works, but it might not fit into your environment, depending on what triggers `check()`.

Comment: On the same page, where `select` is selected, and JavaScript code is executed, PHP can not echo the $_POST['del'] on Client Side.

Answer (score 0):

```
var delvar = "<? $_POST["del"]; ?>";
```

You are trying to combine javascript and php but we don't have that type of possibility because javascript is client side scripting language, PHP is server side scripting language.
There is another way to combine javascript & php. Please refer [this link](http://programmingbulls.com/how-generate-javascript-within-php-dynamically).